¿Cómo puedo añadirle ciertos estilos a un checkbox al hacer focus, solo cuando lo hago presionando tab?
Estoy intentando implementar soporte para el teclado en la app web de Librería que estoy creando. Por eso quiero que, al seleccionar los checkbox .readed (que son para saber si un libro ha sido leído o no) con la tecla tab se le aplique a este un outline: 3px solid var(--color-black); pero que no se apliquen estos estilos si le doy click. Abajo les muestro el codigo HTML/JS(los libros se añaden dinámicamente) y CSS relacionado con el .readed.
Código JS
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="readed" ${book.readed ? "checked" : ""} tabindex="0">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

Codigo CSS
.readed:focus + .slider {
    outline: 3px solid var(--color-black);
}

Cómo ven, los estilos se aplican cuando se hace focus en ese elemento, independientemente de si lo hace mediante un click o por el teclado. Llevo un buen rato intentando darle solución a este inconveniente, pero no lo he logrado. Les agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que puedan ofrecerme.

quizás te funcione usar pointer-events: none; en tu css, eso evitará lo del click y el mouseover, y creo que no afecta en nada el focus de la tecla tab

readed no existe. El pasado de read es read, solo se diferencian en la pronunciación. Es tu librería y puedes nombrar las cosas como quieras, pero escribir las cosas de manera correcta ayuda a la legibilidad del código! Si tienes dudas, chatgpt, deepl o incluso una simple búsqueda en google suelen tardar segundos en ofrecerte la respuesta correcta

@Benito-B gracias por corregir mi error. El Inglés lo he ido aprendiendo poco a poco a medida que leo documentación y me comunico con otros, así que me defiendo en este idioma. Pero me equivoco en ocasiones. Y si, tienes razón, no es bueno que mi código tenga nombres mal escritos, afecta la legibilidad. So, thank you very much.

Debes usar :focus-visible, en la documentación dice:

Este selector es útil para proporcionar un indicador de enfoque
diferente basado en la modalidad de entrada del usuario (ratón vs
teclado).

En el siguiente ejemplo, puede ver que si el botón obtiene el foco con:

Tab: EL fondo es azul
Mouse: El fondo es verde


input:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
input:focus-visible {
  background-color: blue;
}
<input type="button" value="A">
<input type="button" value="B">
<input type="button" value="C">




